# How to prevent printing the variable name using `Data::Dumper`

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I'm using `Data::Dumper` to print a perl hash with configuration, which will be evaluated by another script. The problem is that it always prints `$VAR =` at the start of output.  I tried settings the `Varname` parameter to empty string, but then i get `$1` instead of `$VAR`. How do I prevent printing the variable name using `Dumper`?

```
my $params = {-PARAMS => 0} #data

local $Data::Dumper::Purity = 1;
local $Data::Dumper::Varname  = "";
print Dumper($params) ;
```

Prints:

```
$1 = {
    '-UPDATE' => 0,
}
```

I want to have:

```
{
    '-UPDATE' => 0,
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply set `$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;` and it should work:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -wle '$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1; print Dumper {-PARAMS => 1}'
{
  '-PARAMS' => 1
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Or use the OO syntax:

```
print Data::Dumper->new([ {-PARAMS => 1 } ])->Terse(1)->Dump;
```